# DetailTextLabel keeps changing in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have set up a UITableView with 3 sections that pulls from 3 NSArrays containing the keys for each section. I tried setting up a switch statement to manually set the detailTextLabels and accessory views for each cell, but every time I scroll the table view, the cells seemingly change on their own. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

This is one method I tried using:

```
switch (indexPath.section) 
{
    // info
    case 0:{
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Duration"]) 
        {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [task stringForDuration];
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Elapsed"]) 
        {
            // elapsed time
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Today"]) 
        {
            UISwitch *todaySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [todaySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(todaySwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [todaySwitch setOn:task.isToday];
            cell.accessoryView = todaySwitch;
            [todaySwitch release];
        }
    }
        break;
    // actions
    case 1:{
        cell.textLabel.text = [actionsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Priority"]) 
        {
            // priority
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Finish Early"]) 
        {
            // finish early
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Set New Time"]) 
        {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Repeating"]) 
        {
            UISwitch *repeatingSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [repeatingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(repeatingSwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [repeatingSwitch setOn:task.isRepeating];
            cell.accessoryView = repeatingSwitch;
            [repeatingSwitch release];
            //cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        }
    }
        break;
    // details
    case 2:{
        cell.textLabel.text = [detailsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Specifics"]) 
        {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = task.specifics;
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Repeated"]) 
        {
            // times repeated
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

And this is another:

```
// Info section
if ([indexPath section] == 0) 
{
    // duration
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [task stringForDuration];
    }
    // elapsed time
    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [task stringForTotalElapsedTime];
    }
    // today status
    if (indexPath.row == 2) 
    {
        UISwitch *todaySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [todaySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(todaySwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [todaySwitch setOn:task.isToday];
        cell.accessoryView = todaySwitch;
        [todaySwitch release];

    }
}
// actions section
if ([indexPath section] == 1) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [actionsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // priority
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    // finish early
    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    // set new time
    if (indexPath.row == 2) 
    {
        //cell.accessoryView = repeatingSwitch;
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    // repeating
    if (indexPath.row == 3) 
    {
        UISwitch *repeatingSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [repeatingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(repeatingSwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [repeatingSwitch setOn:task.isRepeating];
        cell.accessoryView = repeatingSwitch;
        [repeatingSwitch release];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
    }
}
// details section
if ([indexPath section] == 2) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [detailsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // specifics
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = taskDetails.specifics;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = task.specifics;
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    // repeated
    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    }
}
```

Both of these attempts were inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You should really quote your most relevant code.

Comment: What ends up happening is that the more I scroll, then the accessory views from some cells and detail text labels from others start appearing in every row, even though it starts out ok. It seems that [indexPath section] does not represent the overall section but rather the displayed section, at least that is the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: Are you aware that your cells are reused and hence will have formerly valid settings still active? You have to entirely reset anything that should be displayed or hidden when initializing a cell.

Comment: But would that explain why initially only the cells I want have accessory views such as a UISwitch in 2 different locations, but after scrolling up and down a few times, there is a UISwitch in every single cell? What about my code causes UISwitches to appear in every cell after a few scrolls?

Comment: The part that adds that switch to the cells. Reused cells will contain that switch if they have formerly been used in section 0 (no matter which section they are used in now). Use different cell identifiers for cells that look entirely different.

Comment: So the dequeue with reuse identifier treats every cell with that identifier as the same? And then only fills in the information right before it is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this question myself, thanks entirely to @Till's comments. It seems the way `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` works is by reusing already existing cells, so in order to use multiple cell types in a table, you have to use different reuse identifiers. Or, since I only have 7 or 8 table view cells, I just set the cell accessory view to nil for all cells that I want to not contain a UISwitch, like so:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

switch ([indexPath section]) 
{
    case 0:
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = task.stringForDuration;
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"00:00";
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                UISwitch *todaySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [todaySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(todaySwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [todaySwitch setOn:task.isToday];
                cell.accessoryView = todaySwitch;
                [todaySwitch release];
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [actionsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Low";
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                UISwitch *repeatingSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [repeatingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(repeatingSwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [repeatingSwitch setOn:task.isRepeating];
                cell.accessoryView = repeatingSwitch;
                [repeatingSwitch release];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [detailsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = task.specifics;
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"0";
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

This way saved me the trouble of dealing with multiple reuse identifiers.